# how to work with hexstrings and bit shifting in golang

Tags: go, hex, buffer, bit-shift

I have a hexademial string that I constructed from arduino sensor `"5FEE012503591FC70CC8"`

This value contains an array of with specific data placed at specific locations of the hex string. Using javascript I can convert the hexstring to a buffer then apply bit shifting operations to extract data, for example battery status like so

```
  const bytes = new Buffer.from("5FEE012503591FC70CC8", "hex");
  const battery = (bytes[8] << 8) | bytes[9];
  console.log(battery)
```

My attemp works but I feel its not optimal like the js way I have shown above

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    hex := "5FEE012503591FC70CC8"
    bat, err := strconv.ParseInt(hex[16:20],16,64)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Battry: ",bat)
}
```

I would really appreciate if someone could show me how to work with buffers or equivalent to the js solution but in go. FYI the battery information is in the last 4 characters in the hex string

Comment: If anything the js is the "un-optimal" method, since you are required to combine the 2 bytes yourself instead of just parsing them into a single number.

Comment: when I said optimal I mean using raw bytes as how its been done in js. I am basically looking at how I can use buffers for the same thing in go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to convert a string of hex-digits into a bytes slice is to use [hex.DecodeString](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/hex#DecodeString):

```
import "encoding/hex"

bs, err := hex.DecodeString("5FEE012503591FC70CC8")
```

you can convert the last two bytes into an `uint16` (unsigned since battery level is probably not negative) in the same fashion as your Javascript:

```
bat := uint16(bs[8])<< 8 | uint16(bs[9])
```

https://play.golang.org/p/eeCeofCathF

or you can use the `encoding/binary` package:

```
bat := binary.BigEndian.Uint16(bs[8:])
```

https://play.golang.org/p/FVvaofgM8W-

Comment: Thank you, I see where I was missing while trying to shit the  I was not casting the bytes to intergers hence reason for getting   (byte_arr[8]) (8 byte_arr) too small for shift of 8

Comment: I like the first solution more because it is the exact position indexed from 0 unlike the second one wher I need to carter for the offset

Comment: `go vet` is a good thing to include in your `go` building process. The playground runs this automatically (as does VScode) - and shows problems like large bit-shifts that `go build` would ignore: https://play.golang.org/p/Dlml8LWx9A3